# Media URL is taking Secure URL https when the website is not secured - Magento 1.x

Tags: magento, https

My site is not secure but still **{{media url }} is taking the https url** when image is inserted via wysiwyg

have entered correct urls under general > web > unsecure & secure sections

Answer (score 0):

Check for following records in core_config_data table:
[image]

Looks like you confused with this variables.